# Integrate REST Web Services with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-rest

I have implemented Restful web services using spring technologies. Now, I need to integrate these services to work together on the same context using spring integration.

How To make web services methods as endpoints ? How can I realize the coreography of web services ? How It is possible to transform messages exchanged between web services ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you following any tutorials which may guide you

Comment: I have founded a lot of articles  but I didn't know how I start ?

Comment: [spring.io/guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) is a good place to start

Answer (score -1):

The [spring-integration](/questions/tagged/spring-integration) tag has links to lots of resources.